# How to pass null on private functions at Junit test [code.getDeclaredMethod] [method.invoke(serviceTest, "aaa",new Object[]{null}) happens an error]

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4, jmockit

I want to test the behaviour of method when an argument is null .
I tried like below but arugment type miss match error happens . What can I do to test it?
I installed Jmockit. but I don't know how to use it.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

ACTUAL CODE

```
    @Test
    public void testLogic() throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        Service serviceTest = new ServiceTest();

        int expected = false;
        Method method = Service.class.getDeclaredMethod("testMethod", String.class, String.class)  ;
        method.setAccessible(true);
        boolean actual = (boolean)method.invoke(serviceTest, "aaa",new Object[]{null});
        assertEquals(false, actual);

    }
```

TEST CODE

```
    private boolean testMethod(String test,String testNull) throws IOException
    {
        if(testNull== null)
        {

            return false;
        }

            return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have all that extra junk in your code.  Why doesn't this work?

```
@Test
public void testLogic() {
    ServiceTest serviceTest = new ServiceTest();
    boolean expected = false;
    boolean actual = serviceTest.testMethod( "aaa", null );
    assertEquals( expected, actual );
}
```

If your only question is how to call a method with reflection, try removing the array.

```
boolean actual = (boolean)method.invoke(serviceTest, "aaa", null );
```

The var args should work normally.

Comment: testMethod(string,string) is private function so It is impossible to build  your test code.

Comment: Then I think the best way is to make the method package private (this is what I do) or use a mock framework that allows you to test private methods (I believe SuperMock does this).

Comment: Updated my answer. @user14232549

Comment: Removing the array occured null point exception in getDeclaredMethod()

Comment: I am thinking of using mock library if there is no other way

Comment: I tried to install JMockit but It wsn't useful..  cause it was unable to  change the value of arugment on method.